# Infragistics Ultragrid Design Mode Keeps Adding RowScrollRegions

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've got a multi-band ultragrid with an ultragridrowedittemplate per band.

In Design view the ultragrid is showing several horizontal lines - which can each be dragged downwards to show a view of the ultragrid bands. After much searching I discovered they are row scroll regions and I've added in some code into the form initialisation procedure to remove these row scroll regions.

That was fine at first, but the ultragrid, over time has added more and more row scroll regions to itself - and when the application is now loaded it takes more and more time for the code to run to remove all these regions.

Is there a setting in the Design mode that stops these row scroll regions being added? I haven't noticed a pattern to when they are added. If someone could explain/help this will be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In design mode drag the divider to the top of the grid to remove them.  To create them there should be a handle just above the scroll bar that you can grab and drag down.  If you want to prevent them from being created at design time or run time, set DisplayLayout.MaxRowScrollRegions to 1.

Note that you may also want to set DisplayLayout.MaxColScrollRegions to 1 as well if you don't want either row or col scroll regions.  To remove ColScrollRegions, drag the divider to the left of the grid to remove them.  There is a handle to the left of the scroll bar if you want to add them back.

Comment: Hi, I already have maxcolscrollregions and maxrowscrollregions set to 1. Although I have dragged the numerous rowscrollregions off screen and they have been removed. It's still adding rowscrollregions every now and then. Thanks for your help

Comment: If the max is already set to 1 for each then you should check your code (including designer generated code) to see if you are adding one anywhere programatically.  If you aren't adding one any where in your code and the max is still set to 1, then it sounds like it would be a bug and you should contact Infragistics support with steps to reproduce the behavior so they can look into it.

Comment: I'll check the designer-generated code. I've got a hunch it might be that then. I've had a lot of issues with having to change the designer code because it doesn't update properly when I've made dataset changes in the designer window. Not my favourite of jobs to do!

Comment: SOLVED: I checked through the Designer window code, somehow a couple of extra lines of code had been added telling it to add a RowScrollRegion. So, this would have happened each time I ran the application. I deleted those lines, and it works fine now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it was in the designer generated code, I would have expected you to see it in the designer as well as at run time.